# Determine if button on dpad is pressed using gdx-controllers

Tags: java, libgdx

Instead of using event based input I'm looking to poll various states.

Mapping for `PS4` controller ..

```
public class PS4 {

    public static final int BUTTON_CROSS = 1;
    public static final int BUTTON_SQUARE = 0;
    public static final int BUTTON_TRIANGLE = 3;
    public static final int BUTTON_CIRCLE = 2;
    public static final int BUTTON_OPTIONS = 9;
    public static final int BUTTON_SHARE = 8;
    public static final int BUTTON_R1 = 5;
    public static final int BUTTON_R2 = 7;
    public static final int BUTTON_R3 = 11;
    public static final int BUTTON_L1 = 4;
    public static final int BUTTON_L2 = 6;
    public static final int BUTTON_L3 = 10;
    public static final int BUTTON_MOUSE = 13;
    public static final int BUTTON_PS = 12;

    public static final PovDirection BUTTON_DPAD_UP = PovDirection.north;
    public static final PovDirection BUTTON_DPAD_DOWN = PovDirection.south;
    public static final PovDirection BUTTON_DPAD_RIGHT = PovDirection.east;
    public static final PovDirection BUTTON_DPAD_LEFT = PovDirection.west;
}
```

Constructor for game `Screen` ..

```
public GameScreen () {

    Controllers.addListener(this);

    if(Controllers.getControllers().size == 0) {

        setHasControllers(false);
        System.out.println("none"); // this is not printed

    } else {

        controller = Controllers.getControllers().first();
    }
}
```

Inside my `render()` method, how do I actually see if a button on dpad is pressed?

```
if (controller.getPov(PovDirection.north)){

    // move character up

    }else if (controller.getPov(PovDirection.south)){
    // move character down
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the controller *is* a PS4 controller.

I don't have a controller with me so you can play around with the string until it is detected

```java
if (controller.getName.toLowerCase().contains("ps4")) {
    ...
}
```

Also, in your game class, you need to implement the interface ControllerListener.

```
public class Game implements ControllerListener {
    ...
}
```

For example, this is the implementation for buttonDown:

```
@Override
public boolean buttonDown(Controller controller, int buttonCode) {
    if (buttonCode == PS4.BUTTON_CROSS) {
        ...
    }
    return false;
}
```

Additionally you should check if the controller being pressing is the same one.